# Apply in pandas depending on row not working

Tags: python, pandas, split, apply

I have a dataframe of buyer's and assistant's names as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
{ 'buyer': 'Lebron James', 'assistant': 'Lebron James' },
{ 'buyer': 'Jon Snow', 'assistant': 'Arya Stark' },
{ 'buyer': 'Frodo Baggins', 'assistant': 'Sam Gamyi' }
])
```

I would like to split the buyer's names into their names and surnames, so the expected output would be:

`first_name  surname
 Lebron       James
 Jon          Snow
 Frodo        Baggings`

For so, I have defined a function and tried to use apply():

```
def first_name(row):
    return df['buyer'][row].split()[0]

df['first_name'] = df.apply(first_name, axis = 1)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-35-f3bcdf3bb991>", line 1, in <module>
    df.apply(first_name, axis = 1)

  File "/Users/javier.lopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6487, in apply
    return op.get_result()

  File "/Users/javier.lopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 151, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()

  File "/Users/javier.lopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 257, in apply_standard
    self.apply_series_generator()

  File "/Users/javier.lopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 286, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)

  File "<ipython-input-32-410cb25f2482>", line 2, in first_name
    return df['buyer'][row].split()[0]

  File "/Users/javier.lopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I had understood that using apply with axis=1 sent the number of the row as argument, so I do not understand why it is not working. If I manually put a row number as argument it works as expected:

```
first_name(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df1 = df['buyer'].str.split(expand=True).rename(columns={0:'first_name',1:"surname"})

print(df1)
  first_name  surname
0     Lebron    James
1        Jon     Snow
2      Frodo  Baggins
```

or:

```
df = df.join(df1)

print(df)
      assistant          buyer first_name  surname
0  Lebron James   Lebron James     Lebron    James
1    Arya Stark       Jon Snow        Jon     Snow
2     Sam Gamyi  Frodo Baggins      Frodo  Baggins
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can use:

```
def first_name(x):
    return x.split()[0]
df['first']=df.buyer.apply(first_name)
print(df)
```

---

```
      assistant          buyer   first
0  Lebron James   Lebron James  Lebron
1    Arya Stark       Jon Snow     Jon
2     Sam Gamyi  Frodo Baggins   Frodo
```

However, as @Sandeep pointed, you should also consider inbuilt pandas solutions as `series.str.split()`, you can directly assign the column using [`df.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
df=df.assign(first=df.buyer.str.split().str[0])
```

---

```
      assistant          buyer   first
0  Lebron James   Lebron James  Lebron
1    Arya Stark       Jon Snow     Jon
2     Sam Gamyi  Frodo Baggins   Frodo
```